# SSMS: Can login with 'localhost' but not 'localhost\MSSQLSERVER'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection, ssms

I guess this is a very basic issue to solve but I've unfortunately spent hours trying to do exactly that... I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition. Everything works fine but I can only connect to the Object Explorer (in Management Studio), using 'localhost' or the machine name, as the server? The error I'm receiving is "...The server was not found or was not accessible..."

I need to be able to connect using `localhost\MSSQLSERVER` or `machinename\MSSQLSERVER`. This is important because my 3rd party application requires the FQDN or server + SQL instance name (which in this case is `MSSQLSERVER`), in order to connect successfully.

Below is a list of things I've done/checked:

- SQL Browser service is running, however when I browser for Local Servers, nothing is displayed.
- In Configuration Manager, all SQL Native and SQL Network options have TCP/IP enabled and Named Pipes enabled (with default ports and settings). SQL Server is running on default port of 1433.
- Everything was installed with local admin account and I'm running SSMS as local admin.
- I haven't been able to find anything useful in the SQL error logs.

Is anyone able to help me with some further troubleshooting steps as I'm border-line stuck for more ideas now...

Thanks for any help.
Jay

Comment: The `MSSQLSERVER` service corresponds to the **default** instance of SQL Server, which has **no instance name** - that's why you can connect to it using `(local)` or `.` or `(machine-name)`. If you **must have** an instance name, then you must install SQL Server as a **named instance** and define an instance name; in that case, you will be able to connect to SQL Server using `(local)\YOURINSTANCE` or `.\YOURINSTANCE` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for same can't find clear solution, please find the apt one based on these insight provided by different dba's & experts on different forums:

- You can use : `select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename` to find    current instance name.
- The general recommendation is that you can change an instance name if it is the **default instance** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx ), but **modifying an existing** named instance is **not recommended** without uninstall/reinstall. SOURCE:[How to rename instance of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c07ab906-dabf-4303-9737-d430d82c4f42/how-to-rename-instance-of-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqltools)
- There is no way you can rename an instance of SQL Server. You can probably **create a new instance** with just the machine name so that it suits you requirements. For more info refer: https://superuser.com/questions/304309/change-sqlexpress-instance-name
- You'll be much much better **reinstalling everything**. Specially with versions SQL 2005 and later, there are just way too many things tied to your instance name: performance counters, local groups for service start and file ACLs, service names for sql and related (agent, full text) services, sql browser visibility, service master key encryption, various full-text settings, registry keys, 'local' linked server and the list can go on for pages and pages. SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907851/change-sql-server-instance-name
- Other Solution can be just **detach the databases, reinstall the instance then attach** the databases again. Changing the server name is fairly easy but it isn't the same as changing the instance name.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The query did return exactly what I expected, however I'm still unable to connect to servername\instancename via SSMS... A re-install will take me hours, it must be something simple happening here but I don't know what.

Comment: I think your'e lucky since seems you hadn't given any instance name in installation & its working on default & The second case above should work & its doesn't require reinstall

Comment: Yes, but with default instance name, I should be still able to connect to localhost\MSSQLSERVER right?

Comment: check if default instance name is `MSSQLSERVER` then only you will be able to connect `localhost\MSSQLSERVER`. Other wise change it like `sp_dropserver <old_name>;
GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local;
GO`, before that read pros & cons for that in msdn article

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, I can't connect to localhost\MSSQLSERVER... only localhost

Comment: What's output of `select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename`?